# good stream definition (mathematical project)

Tags: scala, stream

I would like to have this suite computed :

```
h(-2)=0
h(-1)=1
h(i)=a(i)*h(i-1)+h(i-2), for i>=0
```

(a is given; for my tests I use a=(1,1,2), it has only 3 terms)

I think the best way is to use streams, so I wrote:

```
val h:Stream[Int]=0#::1#::(h.zipWithIndex.zip(h.tail).zip(h.tail.tail)).map{case(((a,i),b),c)=>{
    liste_a(i-2)*b+a
}}
def h2(i:Int)=h(i+2)
```

but I have a ...stack overflow error, and I don't know where it comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a stack overflow because of this: `h.tail.tail`. This will try to compute the third element of `h` (since streams are strict in their `head`), and computing that requires the expression that uses `h.tail.tail`, resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: I think the stack overflow comes because there is no termination condition in the recursion. If there were, your explanation would apply to why there was an argument beyond which the stack overflow began occurring.

Comment: @RandallSchulz Nah, you can define fibonacci like this, without a terminating condition. Here: `val fib: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: 1 #:: ((fib zip fib.tail) map { case (a, b) => a + b })`.

Comment: @Daniel ,hi, I did not understood you fine, I don't see the difference between the working fib.tail and the wrong h.tail.tail. Also, could you explain me how I could make to avoid this error?

Comment: ok, I've understood; my definition needs at least 3 initial values (e.g. 0 #:: 1 #:: 2 #:: etc...).thanks